# using ansible to install vscode skips installing extentions

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, automation, ansible

I'm trying to set up a role that installs VScode on development computers that I'm setting up. I have this inside a role that will be built upon by other roles. I've installed both gantsign.visual-studio-code and gantsign.visual-studio-code-extensions through galaxy, and have them in a requirements file for future use.

My file structure looks like:

```
project
│   requirements.yml
│   playbook.yml  
│
└───roles
│   └───general
|   |   └───tasks
|   |   |   |    main.yml
```

inside my playbook, I call the role like this:

```
  roles:
    role: general
```

and inside the main.yml in the general role, I'm trying to install vs code with the following:

```
- name: install vs code
  ansible.builtin.include_role:
    name: gantsign.visual-studio-code
    public: yes
  vars:
    users:
      - username: myusername
        visual_studio_code_extentions:
          - ms-python.python
          - ms-vscode.cpptools
          - espressif.esp-idf-extension
          - eamodio.gitlens
          - xaver.clang-format
          - GitHub.copilot
```

VS code seems to install properly, but the output when I get to installing the extensions is the following:

```
TASK [gantsign.visual-studio-code : Install (apt)] *****************************
included: /home/adamlichter/.ansible/roles/gantsign.visual-studio-code/tasks/install-apt.yml for instance

TASK [gantsign.visual-studio-code : Install dependencies (apt)] ****************
changed: [instance]

TASK [gantsign.visual-studio-code : Create APT keyrings dir] *******************
ok: [instance]

TASK [gantsign.visual-studio-code : Install key (apt)] *************************
changed: [instance]

TASK [gantsign.visual-studio-code : Install VS Code repo (apt)] ****************
changed: [instance]

TASK [gantsign.visual-studio-code : Install VS Code (apt)] *********************
changed: [instance]

TASK [gantsign.visual-studio-code : Install extensions] ************************
skipping: [instance]

TASK [gantsign.visual-studio-code : Create config directories for users] *******
skipping: [instance] => (item=myusername) 
skipping: [instance]

TASK [gantsign.visual-studio-code : Create settings directory] *****************
skipping: [instance] => (item=myusername) 
skipping: [instance]

TASK [gantsign.visual-studio-code : Write settings] ****************************
skipping: [instance] => (item=myusername) 
skipping: [instance]

TASK [gantsign.visual-studio-code : Write keybindings] *************************
skipping: [instance] => (item=myusername) 
skipping: [instance]
```

how do I prevent it from skipping installing the extensions? is this even something that I can do within a role? or if I'm using a role from galaxy would that have to go inside my top playbook?